# Using dynamic value in s:select dropdown based on the resource bundle by locale in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, dropdown, ognl

I am using a dropdown to display the *status* for a given field, however, I can't populate the field based on the *resource bundle by locale*. In any case, the field is displayed in *English only*.

The `status` is populated in the list through an `enum`, which has values like

```
public enum Status{
    REQUESTED(0), CANCELED(-1), VALIDATED(10), ONGOING(20), FINISHED(30);

    private int intValue;

    private Status(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name();
    }

    public static Status getStatusFromEnum(int code) {
        for (Status status : RackMaintenanceRequestStatus.values()) {
            if (status.getIntValue() == code) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Status getStatusFromString(String name) {
        for (Statusstatus : Status.values()) {
            if (status.name().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return status;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have added the translation in an `ApplicationResource.properties` property file for the `respective fields` in the `enum`.

Here is my `s:select` code:

```
<s:select id="requestStatus"
value="myFormBean.filterStatus"
name="myFormBean.filterStatus"
list="myFormBean.listStatus"
style="width:100%;" cssClass="form-control select2"
listKey="intValue" listValue="name" multiple="true"
size="5" />
```

How can I dynamically populate values from the `enum` based on the `Locale`? Ideally, I try doing it with an `fmt message key` as shown below, but it is not happening with `s:select` here.

```
<fmt:message key="${name}"></fmt:message>
```

Comment: Can you show me your `Action` class, `struts.xml`, and `ApplicationResources.*`?